# php mailer how to set autorespond

Tags: php

As my PHP is level is low and I am only using PHP for this task. Could someone help me implement in my code autorepsond. I want to send email to email address that was put into email input field. Some thing like thank you for contact....

Everything is working fine.

ALso i how to implement that user needs to check checkbox to send mail

```
    <?php
    // Message Vars
    $msg = '';
    $msgClass = '';

    // Check For Submit
    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')){
        // Get Form Data
        $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

        // Check Required Fields
        if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($message)){
            // Passed
            // Check Email
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                // Failed
                $msg = 'Please use a valid email';
                $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
            } else {
                // Passed
                $toEmail = '';
                $subject = 'Contact Request From '.$name;
                $body = '<h2>Contact Request</h2>
                    <h4>Name</h4><p>'.$name.'</p>
                    <h4>Email</h4><p>'.$email.'</p>
                    <h4>Message</h4><p>'.$message.'</p>
                ';

                // Email Headers
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" ."\r\n";
                $headers .="Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

                // Additional Headers
                $headers .= "From: " .$name. "<".$email.">". "\r\n";

                if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers)){
                    // Email Sent
                    $msg = 'Your email has been sent';
                    $msgClass = 'alert-success';
                } else {
                    // Failed
                    $msg = 'Your email was not sent';
                    $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Failed
            $msg = 'Please fill in all fields';
            $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
        }
    }
?>

    <div class="container"> 

      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $name : ''; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $email : ''; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control"><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? $message : ''; ?></textarea>
          </div>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: So, this is correctly sending one email, and you want to send a second one to the person that filled out the form? Or you want the existing email to *also* go to that person?

Comment: I want to send back to this person email "thank you for subscription". so send back  somethink, but not the mail he sent

Comment: What happened when you tried copying the code here that sends an email, and edited things like the To address and the body?

Comment: i do not understand?

Comment: The implication was that you have fully functional code for sending an email, you could just copy it and make the required changes. StackOverflow isn't about getting people to write your code for you, it's about people helping you solve problems with your code. You'll generally get better results if you make an attempt, show your code, and explain what's not working about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update **if** block where mail is being sent.

```
if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers)){
 // Email Sent
 $msg = 'Your email has been sent';
 $msgClass = 'alert-success';
//add this line, it'll send mail to form submitter.
mail($email, "We received your mail", "Thank you for contacting us, we'll get you back soon" , $headers);
}
```

Comment: @Damian You're Welcome

Comment: i have a one more. How to implement into my validation that checkbox needs to be checked if not tthey can't send email??

Comment: @Damian add checkbox in html form then check in php code.